# $scope.$on undefined in controller during unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

My controller works great.  But when I want to test it in karma the $scope.on method comes up as undefined.

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('DataController', [
  '$scope', 'DataProvider' function($scope, DataProvider) {
    $scope.customData = [];
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
      DataProvider.getData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.customData = response.data.customData;
        });
      });
  }
]);
```

Here is my test:

```
'use strict';

describe('DataController', function(){

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp', [])
  });

  it('exists', inject(function($controller) {
    var myCtrl = $controller('DataController', { $scope: {} });
    expect(myCtrl).toBeDefined();
  }));

});
```

Comment: You want to do `$scope:$rootScope.$new()` instead of `$scope:{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$scope` is not really angular `scope` object, it is a mere empty object. You need to create a new child scope of `$rootScope` in this case to have the `$on` method available in the injected `$scope`.

Try:-

```
  it('exists', inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    var myCtrl = $controller('DataController', { $scope: $rootScope.$new() });
    expect(myCtrl).toBeDefined();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was writing my test incorrectly.

I needed to instantiate a scope and inject it in.  Also a key point was making the scope and myCtrl variable available to all of the tests.

```
describe('DataController', function(){
 var scope, myCtrl;
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp');
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    myCtrl = $controller('DataController', { $scope: scope });
    scope.$digest();

  }));
  it('exists', function() {
    expect(myCtrl).toBeDefined();
  });

 });
```

Now I just need to figure out how to fire off the $stateChangeSuccess event in a unit test.